# goneMargin in ConstraintLayout with Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to use ConstraintLayout in Compose. I want the second Composable to be constrained at the end of the first Composable. The first composable can exist or not. In each case, I would like to have different margins. Thus, I use `goneMargin` but this seems to not be respected. Do I need to do something else?

```java
ConstraintLayout {
    val (firstItemRef, secondItemRef) = createRefs()

    if (isFirstItemVisible) {
        Text(
            text = "First",
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(firstItemRef) {
                top.linkTo(anchor = parent.top)
                start.linkTo(anchor = parent.start)
            }
        )
    }

    Text(
        text = "Second",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(secondItemRef) {
            top.linkTo(anchor = parent.top)
            start.linkTo(anchor = firstItemRef.end, margin = 8.dp, goneMargin = 16.dp)
        }
    )
}
```

As a workaround, we could do something like that, but this seems to counterfeit the purpose of `goneMargin`

```java
Text(
    text = "Second",
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(secondItemRef) {
        val margin = if (isFirstItemVisible) 8.dp else 16.dp
        val end = if (isFirstItemVisible) firstItemRef.end else parent.end
        top.linkTo(anchor = parent.top)
        start.linkTo(anchor = end, margin = margin)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `visibility` property in `ConstrainScope` like this:

```kotlin
ConstraintLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val (firstItemRef, secondItemRef) = createRefs()
    Text(
        text = "First",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(firstItemRef) {
            top.linkTo(anchor = parent.top)
            start.linkTo(anchor = parent.start)
            // >> This is what you want <<<
            visibility = if (isFirstItemVisible) Visibility.Visible else Visibility.Gone
        }
    )
    Text(
        text = "Second",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(secondItemRef) {
            top.linkTo(anchor = parent.top)
            start.linkTo(anchor = firstItemRef.end, margin = 8.dp, goneMargin = 16.dp)
        }
    )
}
```